# how to sketch mechanical drawings and pcb of the electronic device?

Tags: 12.04, software-recommendation

I  am trying to sketch pcb and mechanical drawings of the electronic device. Are there any application which is available for Ubuntu 12.04 ?

Note : Application should suggest left-right-up-down arrow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### I'd recommend starting with *Electric*

- I recommend [**Electric**](http://packages.ubuntu.com/electric) [image: Install electric]  for beginners as an easy to use software that will handle both basic PCB layout and also basic electro-mechanical drawings.
- It has a *very nice* online/PDF manual available [here](http://www.staticfreesoft.com/documentsUser.html).
- Here's a sample screenshot with all it's capabilities (from their website; ignore the Windows, the software is in Java and runs fantastically on Ubuntu):

  [image]
- For a much more comprehensive *suite* of EDA tools, look at [**gEDA**](http://packages.ubuntu.com/geda) [image: Install geda]. This will let you lay out complicated PCBs, schematics, VLSI design, SPICE simulation, etc.